# Code is absolutely correct but it showing Sid as invalid identifier

Tags: oracle, plsql, package

```
create or replace package body stu_package

as

procedure select_student(id number)

is

name varchar2(20);

begin

select sname into name from students where sid=id;

dbms_output.put_line(name);

end select_ student;

end stu_package;
```

Comment: Please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Answer (score 6):

Not "absolutely" correct as there's a space you should remove at the end of the procedure:

```
end select_ student;
```

---

Apart from that, yes - it is OK. Test case:

```
SQL> create table students (sid number, sname varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL> insert into students values (1, 'LF');

1 row created.
```

Package specification:

```
SQL> create or replace package stu_package as
  2    procedure select_student(id number);
  3  end;
  4  /

Package created.
```

Package body:

```
SQL> create or replace package body stu_package
  2  as
  3    procedure select_student(id number)
  4    is
  5      name varchar2(20);
  6    begin
  7      select sname into name from students where sid=id;
  8      dbms_output.put_line(name);
  9    end select_student;              --> remove a space
 10  end stu_package;
 11  /

Package body created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> exec stu_package.select_student(1);
LF

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

Therefore, although you said that everything is OK, it appears that column name isn't `sid`:

```
SQL> alter table students rename column sid to id;

Table altered.

SQL> create or replace package body stu_package
  2  as
  3    procedure select_student(id number)
  4    is
  5      name varchar2(20);
  6    begin
  7      select sname into name from students where sid=id;
  8      dbms_output.put_line(name);
  9    end select_student;
 10  end stu_package;
 11  /

Warning: Package Body created with compilation errors.

SQL> show err
Errors for PACKAGE BODY STU_PACKAGE:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- --------------------------------------------------------------
7/5      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
7/48     PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "SID": invalid identifier
SQL>
```

---

Or, maybe you enclosed its name into double quotes while creating the table (if so, don't do that!):

```
SQL> alter table students rename column id to "sid";

Table altered.

SQL> select * From students;

       sid SNAME
---------- ----------
         1 LF

SQL> create or replace package body stu_package
  2  as
  3    procedure select_student(id number)
  4    is
  5      name varchar2(20);
  6    begin
  7      select sname into name from students where sid=id;
  8      dbms_output.put_line(name);
  9    end select_student;
 10  end stu_package;
 11  /

Warning: Package Body created with compilation errors.

SQL> show err
Errors for PACKAGE BODY STU_PACKAGE:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- --------------------------------------------------------------
7/5      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
7/48     PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "SID": invalid identifier
SQL>
```

So, if you really used double quotes, you'll have to do that all the time:

```
SQL> create or replace package body stu_package
  2  as
  3    procedure select_student(id number)
  4    is
  5      name varchar2(20);
  6    begin
  7      select sname into name from students where "sid"=id;     --> here
  8      dbms_output.put_line(name);
  9    end select_student;
 10  end stu_package;
 11  /

Package body created.

SQL>
```

Comment: Okay I understood what I have done wrong.now I rectified that problem

Comment: OK; I'm glad you fixed it.